# Optimizing a function with two parameters (one continuous and one integer value)

Tags: r

Using the language R, I am trying to optimize the two-parameter function f(x,y) such that x,y are both non-negative and y is an integer. However, I do not get the simple answer one would get on paper.

Define

```
f = function(param){
  x=param[1] ; y=round(param[2])
  temp = (x-1.3)^2+(y-1.7)^2
  return(temp)
}
```

Clearly, the answer is x=1.3 and y=2, but given the set-up, any value of y in (1.5,2.49) is acceptable as round(y)=2. This is what I get from the constrOptim function though:

```
constrOptim(c(1,4),f,ui=rbind(c(1,0),c(0,1)),ci=c(0,0) , method="Nelder-Mead")

$par
[1] 1.299810 4.016033

$value
[1] 5.29

$counts
function gradient 
      43       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

$outer.iterations
[1] 2

$barrier.value
[1] -6.084598e-05
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your starting point for y is 4. if you set it around 2 it will give you what you expect. I think the problem is that your objective function is perfectly flat in certain regions and has discontinuities, so there is not always a meaningful gradient to follow to the global minimum. for x = 0.1 your function looks like this:[image]

so the optimization procedure is going to have a hard time to give you the correct result. one option is to substitute the round() function with a smoother version of it.

Comment: Yes, objective function is locally flat relative to y. However, the point is to eliminate the sensitivity to the initial value so that in examples where the actual solution is unknown one can be fairly confident of converging to global minimum. I have also tried penalizing, i.e temp = (x-1.3)^2+(y-1.7)^2 + penalty*(y-param[2])^2 to force integer answers, but no luck. I am afraid that while smoother function than round() might be helpful in certain cases, but here it will not force the integer value for y which is of primary interest. Also, I have used Nelder-Mead which is not gradient based.

Comment: Given all of this, your point about local flatness relative to y is crucial. Do you know if I can set the step size delta for the optimization function constrOptim() to one value for x and to another value for y? If the step size for y is large, it will get the optimizer out of local flatness, which, hopefully, resolves the problem.

Comment: I am sorry I do not know the answer to the step size question, I have used this very seldom. I see the point of our reasoning though.